# Android: getting classcastexception when creating button on fragment

Tags: java, android, button

here is the fragment code.

I am trying to create a button inside but i keep getting an error.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    Button startButton;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView;
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        startButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.enter);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.appname.STUFF"));
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

    }
}
```

here is the error i keep getting. I dont know why, ive tried doing this in many locations and still get this error.

```
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appname/com.appname.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at com.appname.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:179)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:928)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1105)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1468)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1132)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3833)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1624)
03-20 20:27:21.093: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    ... 11 more
```

Here is the XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.appname.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
        android:text="Enter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TITLE"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `R.id.enter` is probably not a button. Can you post XML?

Comment: @Szymon i added it now

Comment: Check your widget import, and try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: can u show your activity code ? also try to change tools:context="com.appname.MainActivity in xml

Comment: @user3439273 Thanks to have accepted my answer. Just for my information, which one of these solutions works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check your import:**

```
import android.widget.Button;
```

**Clean and rebuild** *(apparently, this changes nothing for you)*.

Remove and **rebuild manually your xml Button**, it's automatically rebuild your R file.

Not sure, but maybe it's related.. **Change your intent method** as:

```
Intent i = new Intent(); 
i.setClassName("com.appname.ACTIVITY", "com.appname.STUFF");
getActivity().startActivity(i);
```

Or use **ClassName without PackageName:**

```
getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), StuffActivity.class);
```

Also make sure you're importing the right class name.

If this does not work, change your `onClickListener` to an **onClick method** like:

```
// in your xml Button
android:onClick="launchActivity"  

// in your Fragment
public void launchActivity(View view) {
    getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), StuffActivity.class);
}
```

You can also call a method from your `Fragment` to `FragmentActivity` as:

```
// Fragment: onClickListener
startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((Activity) getActivity()).launchActivity();
    }
}

// FragmentActivity: launchActivity method
public void launchActivity() {
    startActivity(new Intent(Activity.this, StuffActivity.class));
}
```

I hope you will achieve what you want.

Comment: The import was importing holo stuff not the regular import android.widget.Button;

Comment: @user3439273 OK, glad to help you with this. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

In you case everything looks correct and I am sure, you should have done proper import.

Eclipse tends to mess up your resources every now and then. This leads to some odd behavior such as strings and images being swapped all over your app, and more commonly classCastException(s), which happen when Eclipse switches your Views' ids around.

**A few solutions to that problem:**

```
Clean your project.

Modify an xml layout file and save.

Delete your R file. (Don't worry it will be automatically generated again).
```

Basically anything that makes your project rebuild and re-generate the R file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ive done this already, and did it again just now and still keep getting the same error

Comment: @user3439273 Can you just try to rename your enter button tag? I mean rename "android:id="@+id/enter"" to something else and try